# Buenas a todos, llevo dias intentando solucionar esto del salto de linea en la celda de una gridview en c# con la tecla Enter

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito calcular la cantidad por el precio del producto en una gridview, lo del calculo ya lo hice pero el problema de al momento de hacerlo, actua el evento, pero de la fila de abajo. y ese problema ocurre despues de digitar el numero y al presionar la tecla Enter.

Se algo del evento KeyDown en la celda pero no me funciona.
He Hecho esto de codigos que he visto en internet. En Youtube no hay nada.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);            
    }

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
        DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Columnas deseadas
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.KeyUp -= new KeyEventHandler(text_KeyDown); 
                tb.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(text_KeyDown);                   
            }
        }
    }

    public void text_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = ((DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)(sender)).EditingControlRowIndex;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;               
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esto es win form, wpf u otra cosa??

Comment: si bro. es una aplcacion de escritorio

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. En el código no aparece nada del calculo que señalas, hay uno textbox metidos que tampoco entiendo. La verdad no se mucho de winforms, pero creé un dataGridView, le pasé una lista y puedo editar los valores y calcular el total sin problema, y tampoco necesité de todos esos eventos que tu pusiste, por eso me parece raro

Comment: gracias bro, la verdad me di un tiempo para hacer esto porquende verdad me estrese. Ahora lo intentare de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar una combinación de endedit y selection change con el preview key para saber cual es, tambien se puede usar sin el preview como lo cogi del [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771594/how-to-prevent-going-to-next-row-after-editing-a-datagridviewtextboxcolumn-and-p) pero creo que funciona mejor de esta manera la logica:

```
   private bool resetRow = false;
    private int[] ints = new int[2];
    private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
        DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Columnas deseadas
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.PreviewKeyDown += Tb_PreviewKeyDown;
                dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += DataGridView1_CellEndEdit;
                dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += DataGridView1_SelectionChanged;
              
            }
        }
    }

    private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(resetRow)
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[ints[0]].Cells[ints[1]];
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        ints[0] = e.RowIndex;
        ints[1] = e.ColumnIndex;
    }

    private void Tb_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            resetRow = true;
        }
        else
            resetRow = false;
    }
```

Comment: este me ha servido mucho pero creo que me falta algo bro, si me pudieras hablar a mi correo porfa. creoq que te estas acercando mucho a lo que necesito. Te dejo mi correo claudiovm.8989@gmail.com